# c# how to sort sizes from list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display my products with sizes from small to large?:

M, XL, S would have to result in : S, M , XL

c#

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<product> list = new List<product>();
            product p1 = new product() {productid=1,Size="M" };
            product p2 = new product() { productid = 2, Size = "XL" };
            product p3 = new product() { productid = 3, Size = "S" };
            list.Add(p1);
            list.Add(p2);
            list.Add(p3);
            List<product> orderlist = list.OrderBy(o => o.Size).ToList();

            //list.Sort(size);
            foreach (var pr in orderlist)
            {
                Response.Write(pr.Size +"<br/>");
            }
        }



   public class product
    {
        public int productid{ get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: there is no question here.

Comment: I don't see a reason to downvote this question. +1

Comment: Agree with dllhell. +1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to change `Size` to an enum in the right order:

```
public enum ClothingSize
{
    [Abbreviation("S")]
    Small = 0,
    [Abbreviation("M")]
    Medium = 1,
    [Abbreviation("L")]
    Large = 2,
    [Abbreviation("XL")]
    ExtraLarge = 3
}
```

(There are various approaches to mapping the enum to its abbreviated text form - I've given one example using an `AbbreviationAttribute` which you'd declare yourself; you *could* use the existing `DescriptionAttribute`, but it's slightly odd for a description to be more terse than the identifier itself.)

Benefits of using the enum:

- Less risk of typos
- Easier to validate that a given size is actually valid (although you would need to do that validation - enums are just named numbers; `(ClothingSize) 15` would give you an inappropriate value, for example
- Natural ordering

Comment: This can become a bit of a mess if you ever add a new size larger than small and smaller XL, though in the case of clothing this probably isn't a concern.

Comment: @Brian: You could easily spread the values out to start with to allow for that later enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

A good approach would be to implement IComparable on the `product` type like this:

```
public class product : IComparable
{
     // YOUR CODE
#region IComparable<Employee> Members

     public int CompareTo( product other )
     {
         // Comparison logic
         // return 1 if other size is greater
         // -1 if other size is smaller
         // 0 if both sizes are equal
     }

#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the ICompareable-Interface in your product-class. The class then looks like:
  public class product : IComparable
    {
        public int productid { get; set; }
        public string Size { get; set; }

```
    /// <summary>
    /// do compare-stuff like if-statement on the size or something else
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="compareProduct">the product to compare with this</param>
    /// <returns>
    /// 0  if both product-sizes are equal
    /// 1  if compareProduct.Size is larger
    /// -1 if this.Size is larger
    /// </returns>
    public int CompareTo(product compareProduct)
    {
        // TODO: implement
    }
}
```

Then you can sort your list by just calling:

```
list.Sort();
```